# Why was my tag suggestion rejected?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, suggested-edits

Today I suggested two tag wikis, one of them was this: https://superuser.com/suggested-edits/9748, that was rejected by user Community.

Does someone knows the reason? Comunity rejected without any explanations. It was framed as low quality?

Comment: Been reported on meta as a bug [Suggested edits to tag wikis are systematically and silently rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126248)

Comment: It wasn't rejected by Community, actually, you'd see “Rejected by Community” under the big red “Rejected”. It's a [bug with suggested edits to tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126248).

Comment: Sure, thank you Sathya and Gilles.

Comment: I applied the tag wikis, such that no work / text / time was lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a side effect of [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126091).  We've deployed a fix, and the erroneously rejected suggestions have been marked as pending.